# android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED

Tags: android, android-intent, alarm, android-alarms

I need to set alarm icon in status bar, without a notification. It works when application is running, but after finishing an application, the receiver does not respond on "ALARM_CHANGED", only on "BOOT_COMPLETED".
Need to set alarm icon after user turns off alarms in build-in Alarm Clock.

Thanks.

manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Alarm.AlarmInitReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

AlarmInitReceiver.java:

```
public class AlarmInitReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() != null) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "BOOT-completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setStatusBarIcon(true);
        }
    }
}
```

}

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setStatusBarIcon(true);
    enableReceiver(true);

}

protected void enableReceiver(boolean enable) {
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(mContext, AlarmInitReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            (enable) ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}

public static void setStatusBarIcon(boolean enabled)
{
    Intent alarmChanged = new Intent("android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED");
    alarmChanged.putExtra("alarmSet", enabled);
    mContext.sendBroadcast(alarmChanged);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
public class AlarmInitReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() != null) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "BOOT-completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED")) {
            if (intent.getExtras().getBoolean("alarmSet") == false) {
                Intent alarmChanged = new Intent("android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED");
                alarmChanged.putExtra("alarmSet", true);
                context.sendBroadcast(alarmChanged);
            }
        }
    }
}
```